# Is this a valid jquery getJSON call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller, getjson

I am using jquery getJSON with asp.net mvc controller... I cant able to get it work....

```
 public JsonResult GetMaterials(int currentPage,int pageSize)
 {
   var materials = consRepository.FindAllMaterials().AsQueryable();
   var results = new PagedList<MaterialsObj>(materials, currentPage-1, pageSize);
   return Json(results);
 }
```

and  i am calling this with,

```
$.getJSON('Materials/GetMaterials', "{'currentPage':1,'pageSize':5}",
 function(data) {
    });
```

This call doesn't seem to work....

when inspected through firebug i found this,

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 
'currentPage' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 
'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetMaterials(Int32, Int32)' in 
'CrMVC.Controllers.MaterialsController'. To make a parameter optional its type
 should be either a reference type or a Nullable type.<br>
 Parameter name: parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, `data` should be an object:

```
$.getJSON('Materials/GetMaterials', {'currentPage':1,'pageSize':5},
 function(data) {
    });
```